# How to access amCharts labels dynamically to change text

Tags: label, amcharts

I am able to add a label to a pie chart by following one of the examples on the amCharts site. Code below. I'm now trying to dynamically access that label by name "center". I am thinking it should be something like chartOverviewAnimated.labels.indexOf("center") or similar, but can't figure it out.

```
var label = chartOverviewAnimated.seriesContainer.createChild(am4core.Label);
label.text = "1";
label.horizontalCenter = "middle";
label.verticalCenter = "middle";
label.fontSize = 50;
label.id = "center";
```